# Custom font for Text in Haskell Diagrams

Tags: haskell, fonts, haskell-diagrams

I'm using Diagrams library to generate some text with a custom font. Looking at the documentation for [Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.4/docs/Diagrams-TwoD-Text.html) it is not clear how can one specify particular .ttf font file? I tried using different .ttf files like in the example below, but no one worked.

```
discountText :: Maybe Int -> Diagram B
discountText discount =
  case discount of
    Nothing -> mempty
    Just value ->
      text (show value ++ " %") # font "Roboto-Light.ttf" # fontSize 90
```

Another alternative seems to be [SVGFonts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SVGFonts), but I would like to achieve this without another library. So how do you guys set custom fonts in Diagrams?

UPD: I find the answer given below very explanatory. To solve the problem I actually ended up using [SVGFonts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SVGFonts) which adds extra step of converting .ttf into .svg, but does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font handling in `Diagrams` is highly dependent on the backend.  `diagrams-cairo` should be able to use any TTF font on your system.  On Linux, it will look up names using FontConfig.  It should use the OS-provided font lookup mechanism on other OSes, but I can't recall ever testing this myself.

What backend are you planning to use?  I'm partial to `diagrams-cairo` for text handling, but it's the most difficult backend to install, especially on not-Linux.  It's likely other backends have improved since the last time I tested their text handling, also.

Comment: I'm using Rasterific, since I'm working with different image formats.

Comment: I'm not certain, but looking at `diagram-rasterific` code for [text rendering](https://github.com/diagrams/diagrams-rasterific/blob/master/src/Diagrams/Backend/Rasterific.hs#L369) and [font selection](https://github.com/diagrams/diagrams-rasterific/blob/master/src/Diagrams/Backend/Rasterific/Text.hs#L69), I think you may need to recompile `diagrams-rasterfic` with your font, or otherwise modify it.